# GSite Crawler stopped working

Tags: url, sitemap, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I use the GSite Crawler v1.23 and had been working OK till a week ago but not now. I used to execute the programme at the office and now I'm trying to run it at home but it doesn't start crawling. I didn't change any setting besides ISP. Anyone can help me how to fix this issue??

Thanks

Comment: Still cannot make it work properly. It used to work without running as admin but now not. And even if I run in as admin, it won't crawl a lot like it used to be. It used to crawl more than 20,000 but now only 4,000. The setting is same as I imported from the previous setting. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a bunch.  You have to right click -> run as administrator.  Fixed it for me.